# Workaround Wildcard in Ant Task jar.destfile

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar

I am using Ant to update a Jar file but the name of the Jar changes often.  I thought of using a wildcard (i.e. `*`) in the `destfile` attribute of `jar` Ant task.  If this were to work, this will allow for the Ant script to remain constant even though the Jar file name changes.  For example...

```
<jar update="true" destfile="myjar*.jar">
   <zipfileset dir="classes"/>
</jar>
```

Unfortunately, `*` is not supported.  I get the following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

How do I update a Jar file which has a changing name?

Technically, the Ant script is being run with `maven-antrun-plugin` so a Maven solution would be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `"myjar*.jar"` could select multiple JARs.

A workaround would be to lookup the first JAR that matches a given name into the wanted folder: this will correspond to the wanted JAR (since we know that there is only one). Then, you can use that JAR to update it.

A sample configuration would be the following. It retrieves the first JAR with the help of the [`first`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#first) resource locator.

```
<first id="jarToUpdate">
    <fileset dir="/path/to/wanted/directory" includes="myjar*.jar" />
</first>
<jar update="true" destfile="${toString:jarToUpdate}">
   <zipfileset dir="classes"/>
</jar>
```